# Java : Read sonar-project.properties

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have defined below properties in sonar-project.properties

```
sonar.directory=project/file
```

In my java application when I tried to read it gives null value any suggestion on how to read the property value ?

```
public class MySensor implements Sensor {

public static String FOLDER = "sonar.directory"; 

public MySensor(FileSystem fs) {
    this.fs = fs;
    FOLDER = System.getProperty("sonar.directory");
    LOGGER.info("folder location {}", FOLDER);
}
```

EDIT- Below is my command to invoke

```
sonar-scanner -Dsonar.host.url="http://localhost:9000" -Dsonar.login=admin -Dsonar.password="admin" -Dsonar.directory=project/file
```

Comment: System.getProperty returns `null` as there's no VM argument. Invoke your app with  `-Dsonar.directory=/tmp`

Comment: @Shahar Yeah while invoking -Dsonar.directory=/tmp it returns null

Comment: Where do you load properties file?

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez - you can define properties file in project location or specify in the command line. No need to load the file explicitly in code. Sonar will read it from command line or from sonar-project.properties

Answer (score 0):

We can use context to read sonar properties.

```
Optional<String> result = context.config().get(sonar.directory);
```